# Wordpress Custom Theme: My site shows the same posts on Page 1 and Page 2 and so on

Tags: posts, pagination, blog

Despite the pagination going to nieuws/page/2, it still shows the same posts as on the first page. This is my PHP code for the blog:

```
<!-- Tekst -->
<div class="page-wrapper" id="nieuws">
  <h1 id="over-ons-h1">Laatste <span>Nieuws</span></h1>
  <div class="lijn" id="text-lijn"></div>
</div>

<!-- Page Code -->
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

      <!--  Posts Loop -->
      <?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'nutrisense_nieuws'
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

      ?>

      <?php if ($the_query->have_posts() ): while ($the_query->have_posts() ) :$the_query->the_post(); ?>

      <div class="posts">
        <h2 class="post-title"><a class="post-title" href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>".><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="calender"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i><p class="post-datum"><?php the_time('j F, Y'); ?></p></div>
        <div class="post-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
        <div class="post-tekst-wrapper"><p class="post-tekst"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></div>
        <p class="post-lees-meer"><a class="post-title" href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>".>Lees meer..</a></p>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php
        previous_posts_link('&laquo; Nieuwere berichten');
        next_posts_link( 'Oudere berichten &raquo;', $the_query->max_num_pages );
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `posts_per_page` and `paged` param.

```
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'nutrisense_nieuws',
      'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'); // number of posts to show per page  
      'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ) // get page if set else page 1, Use "page" for static front page instead of "paged" see the links. 
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Check these first

[Get Query Var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

[WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)